# Having a local JSON file within my Xcode project

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

Quick question, I'm sending in my app to Apple and my app uses a json file which is stored locally within the project. Will Apple turn the app down because of that or will it go through?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem, but why not convert to a plist? I hate XML myself but for any local files I convert to plists as it's no wasted time at all.

Comment: Same, seems I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not be an issue, they won't reject it for that reason.